# Run a python command from a .yaml file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml, google-cloud-platform

I have a python project working locally which runs under the UNIX command format of: python main.py arg1 arg2 etc.

I want to export my folder to the Google App Engine, so I did the small tutorial to make "Hello World" run on my App. I read the app.yaml file but can't seem to figure out how to add an app.yaml to my project that runs my Python command.

EDIT:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
args: ["python webXMLPARSER.py www.reitmans.com 2016-12-01 2016-12-08"]
```

Comment: standard or flex environment?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Standard environment

Comment: Better to create a SO tag for GAE standard and flexible environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer - you cannot do that.

The long one now.

GAE (standard) app code is not designed to run as a standalone app.  It is merely a collection of config files and code snippets designed to work together with and complement the GAE infra code (live or SDK) in order to operate as an app.

To run the app locally one must do it through the SDK's development server, see [Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-server) for details.

Also:

- GAE apps are fundamentally web server apps, they get requests and return responses, they don't actually execute arbitrary python cmds. Your attempted config is invalid, see [app.yaml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref).
- the GAE sandbox has significant restrictions when it comes to what the app can do, in particular launching other processes is not allowed. See [The sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Python_The_sandbox).

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to instruct to run a shell, and then pass arguments to the shell like python something.py args1 args2.

```
command: bash -c "python something.py args1 args2"
```

You should try Dockerfiles[1](http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/#dockerfile), they have a more intuitive way of running commads:

```
CMD ["python", "something.py", "args1", "args2"]
```

Comment: I get the error: Configuration is not valid: Unexpected attribute 'command' for object type AppInfoExternal.

Comment: EDIT: Do you have a simple .yaml example, I'm pretty new to .yaml files.

Comment: You have your .yaml? can you update the question? Edited the answer, could you try it?

Comment: Answer edited. It looks like alot of code is missing, when I see other yaml files they're like 20 lines and over, but all I need is run a command line.

Comment: I think that you are using the wrong stack (GAE) for a web parser. It's better to use Google Cloud Engine for parsers. I thought you were using GCE instead of GAE. Dockerfiles and yamls are more flexible there and it's cheaper.  I'm not sure what could be the mistake, but I can help you deploying it in GCE.